# Does my design break modularity and loose coupling?

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I want to know if my implementation is modular and loosely coupled such that pieces can be replaced easily.

[image]

Any concrete class that extends the abstract class `HexGridLayout` will be expected to update the field `coords` by using the field `center` of the `HexGrid`.

Does passing `HexGrid` to the `HexGridLayout` break the modularity and cause tight coupling? **Is this a good design approach to making the `coords` and `center` field updates modular?**

I'd be glad to hear any suggestions to improve my implementation as well,
Thanks!

Comment: **I** don't respect it, and neither should you. Design patterns don't solve problems, programmers do, if the implementation you've created solves a problem for you then you're doing great. Don't worry yourself over whether or not you followed some spec for a particular tool - just worry about whether or not you created a tool that makes your job easier and *doesn't make it harder*. Often times overuse of design patterns or following them *precisely* involves doing extra unnecessary stuff that makes them less useful for your particular situation. Solve your *problem*, not *the design pattern*.

Comment: I asking this question because, I want my code to be modular...for future purposes.

Comment: Then ask if your code is modular; or better yet - decide for yourself through your own personal analysis if it's modular. No design pattern causes modularity, good design that doesn't break modularity does. If you want to know whether or not your code is modular you should ask that- but I think you would need to state your misgivings regarding it's modularity - things like "I'm not sure if X is going to be maintainable because of Y" or what not so we have specific conerns to respond to. Your question is probably OK as it is, I just discourage zealous following of "patterns" over solutions

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Thanks you for the edits. English isn't my first language. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not encourage your specific approach; it *is* modular and does appear totally functional, but I would suggest a slight change.

I would encourage you to invert the relationship between the `HexGrid` and `HexGridLayout` such that instead of the `HexGridLayout` directly accessing and changing the `coords` and `center` properties, instead it takes them as parameters and returns a new set of values.

Then there's two choices to getting the `coords` and `center` fields updated:

1. You can give whatever `HexGridLayout` you want to use to the `HexGrid` and the `HexGrid` will call `update(coords, center)` and receive new values for `coords` and `center` which it will set on itself.
2. If currently `HexGrid` isn't the one calling `update` - then whichever class *is* calling it on `HexGridLayout` should call `update(hexGrid.coords, hexGrid.center)` and retrieving the updated `coords`/`center` values it updates it's instance of `HexGrid` itself.

I encourage number 2 above, because this completely decouples `HexGridLayout` from `HexGrid` while making available the updated `coords` and `center` values to any who wish to use them to update a `HexGrid` - you could use 1 `HexGridLayout` to get updated values for any number of `HexGrid`s because of this loose coupling, or just use it to log or even project future updates etc.

So, as it stands, your design *is* modular, though I wouldn't quite claim it's utterly loosely coupled - because your `HexGridLayout` is completely reliant on your implementation of `HexGrid` and cannot be used to layout *other* types of `HexGrid` (perhaps a network based `HexGrid` would be useful for client/server functionality which your `HexGridLayout` currently wouldn't support for instance).

Comment: In this case, I program in Java. I know that Java pass parameters by value. So, how can I implement your solution (one) by passing `coords` and `center`. Thanks for your help.